# popup not opening after setting a flash message and redirect on same page in yii2

Tags: popup, yii2

I made a password change page in yii2. after changing the password i set a success flash message and re directed it on same page.When it re directed no Popup is opening while i clicked on login link

Comment: You  need to provide more information before anyone can give you a useful answer. include i.e. the details of the page

Comment: Do popups work if you redirect to another page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution..This happening because of the flash message i was giving..